# Delete feature using event receiver on a farm feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, feature, event-receivers, feature-stapling

There is a farm feature and there  is a `web-scoped` feature. Web feature does stuff on multiple sites. If ever i want to get rid of the feature on all sites, I have a farm feature that has on deactivate following code, while `on-activate` is empty(no logic):
Is there something wrong with my code??  I get and error:

> value does not fall within the expected range

```
          public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        SPSite tmpRoot = new SPSite("http://omac-spsdev01");
        SPSiteCollection tmpRootColl = tmpRoot.WebApplication.Sites;
        foreach (SPSite site in tmpRootColl)
        {
            foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
            {
                string FeatureID = "5f71dfd4-20dd-432f-ae60-60e31f5e972b";
                //Get feature Guid  
                Guid myfeatureid = new Guid(FeatureID);

                //remove feature

                //SPFeatureCollection features = web.Features;
                //SPFeature myfeature = features[FeatureID];

                if (web.Features[myfeatureid] != null)   //Make sure Feature is installed!
                {
                    web.Features.Remove(myfeatureid);//deactivate feature
                }
                web.Dispose();
            }

            site.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a StackTrace, so we can see what line is actually causing the error?

Comment: I have updated the trace log.. I am so mad right now I wanna get to the bottom of this $hit

Answer (score 1):

`SPWeb.Features` only contains activated features. If you call `web.Features[myfeatureid];` on a web that does not have that feature activated then it will blow up in the exact manner you describe.

**Updated with code - you want something like this:**

```
if (oWeb.Features[id] != null)
{
     oWeb.Features.Remove(id);
}
```

(The looping I had talked about before was actually for event receivers and not features so I have since removed that remark - I apologize for the confusion)

Comment: I have  updated my code, but it still throws the same error!!! please help!

Comment: The updated code don't check if your feature is activated, it only checks that at least one feature is activated. In fact now it'll break on all sites as it'll try to deactivate you feature as many times as there are features activated

Comment: Will this do it?   if ((myfeature != null) & (myfeature.DefinitionId==myfeatureid))    //Make sure Feature is installed!
                        {
                            web.Features.Remove(myfeatureid);//deactivate feature
                        }

Comment: Updated with code. Let me know how it works.

Comment: @ToddersLegrande Now I have a different error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."..

Comment: Can you post your updated code and possibly a stack trace?

Comment: @ToddersLegrande I have updated my code. One thing to note is this is a farm feature and I am trying to access the features in all webs (web-scoped features) Am I accessing the objects properly? I know I can't use spcontext here..

Comment: A stack trace would tell us which line its blowing up on and subsequently which object you are accessing improperly. The good news is your remove code now looks right. Are you able to attach a debugger and figure out which object is null? Is it Site, Web, Features, or the Feature itself?

Comment: @ToddersLegrande This is where I am having problem: i wanna find out this myself. How do I view the stacktrace? How do I debug an event receiver like any other project? DO i attach a process like IExplore or w3wp? Please guide me here. This would be like teaching how to fish instead of giving me a fish !! :)

Comment: A stack trace is essentially the chain of methods that are called that produced the error. It should contain your method name "FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)" as well as any other methods that were called to reach that point. It should be a mess of code looking stuff that comes with the error you found. If its not, it should definitely be in the ULS log atc:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Comment: @ToddersLegrande can it be a permission related issue, as the logic is implemented on the farm feature?? I have updated the trace.. would adding elevated privilege logic work here?

Comment: All the web-scoped feature does is change siteicon on all new web instances and all I am wanting to do is "whatif people wanted to revert back to original icon? scenario" I would have to undo all the changes by either manually deactivating the feature on each website or using powershell or object model. I chose object model, so it would be one bang and the thing would revert back to the original icon for all sites on deactivation of the farm feature..

Comment: It could be permissions related. You could run with elevated privileges to see if that helps. The interesting thing is it looks like it did deactivate the feature but then ran into an error later (posisbly in your second loop or something). So its possible your account doesn't have access to the subsequent webs or site collections or something. If you can't attach a debugger you could try logging messages throughout the routine to figure out where its blowing up and what the values are when it happens.

Comment: Also, instead of elevating permissions, you could update the user policy on the web app to allow the account you are deactivating the feature from full control access across the web application